# IOS: UIWebView: youtube video thumbnail not fitting inside UIWebview

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am embedding youtube video inside a UIWebView. The Size of the UIWebView is 124x86. And the Code for the same is:

```
NSString* embedHTML =@"\
    <html><head>\
    <style type=\"text/css\">\
    body {\
    background-color: transparent;\
    color: white;\
    }\
    </style>\
    </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
    <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
    width=\"124\" height=\"86\"></embed>\
    </body></html>";
```

When Loaded, the thumbnail doesn't show up properly. its size is way bigger than 124x86 and not fitting into UIWebView. (So now I can see only 1/4th portion of the thumbnail).

I want that thumbnail gets shrinks (or gets generated) to the size of 124x86 and fits into UIWebView.